# add variable in AppDelegate Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables, appdelegate

I am trying to add two variabled in my appDelegate so that I can use them in other my view controller.

My code looks like this:

myappdelegate.h:

```
@class MyViewController1, MyViewController2; // controller than use my new variables

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSString* firstVariable; 
    NSString* secondVariable; 
}
@property (retain) NSString* firstVariable;
@property (retain) NSString* secondVariable;

@end
```

In myappdelegate.m I synthesized the variables:

```
...
@synthesize firstVariable = _firstVariable;
@synthesize secondVariable = _secondVariable;
...
```

But when in my viewcontroller use myappdelegate don't find my new variables:

```
...
mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
...
mainDelegate.firstVariable = localVariable.text;
...
```

where is my error??

Thanks to all.

Comment: There are a number of errors.  A major one is that the names of your instance variables are different from the names you use when synthesizing your properties.  Also, you don't need the `@class` line unless your delegate accesses those controllers.  Does your view controller import "AppDelegate.h"?  How do you declare `mainDelegate`?

Comment: Argh! Using the app delegate to pass data between your view controllers! You might as well tattoo a sign on your forehead that says "I don't know what I'm doing".

Comment: So, was there an error message?

Comment: You may need to import the AppDelegate.h file into your other class.

Comment: Yes, I imported the AppDelegate.h into my other class, but not found!

Comment: I Declared mu mainDelegate in my sendButtonAction method... and I use it in the same method..

Comment: Are you not using ARC.... or Objective C 2.0 O.O? You shouldn't have the instance variables, you shouldn't have the retain (this hasn't been needed since ARC) and you shouldn't have the @synthesize as this is auto done for you for quite some time (either iOS 5 - 6). ... and be consistent with your pointer location >.@. And sorry, I agree with Abizern. I don't know what your doing here, but it definitely doesn't seem like you should be doing it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid if your instance variables and your @synthesize statement. The compiler will do that work for you.

Make sure you `#import AppDelegate.h` every place you need it, particularly in MyViewController1.m and MyViewController2.m.

My guess is that you didn't import the AppDelegate.h file in your view controller's .m files.

As @Abizern says, using the app delegate to pass data is not a good design pattern. You should keep your app delegate simple, only responding to delegate messages and notifications.

Better to create a data container singleton and use that to share data between objects in your project.

Comment: I'm sure I imported my appDelegate in both my viewController. I use my appdelegate to set two status.. not to pass data.. I need to set one status when I insert data...

Comment: Status is a form of data.

Comment: yes, I create a class with my propriety I change in other class. Now i find all my propriety and I change them in all my function. thank you Duncan

Answer (score 0):

```
Code:
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSString* firstVariable;
    NSString* secondVariable;
}
@property (retain) NSString* firstVariable;
@property (retain) NSString* secondVariable;


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize firstVariable;
@synthesize secondVariable;


Inside your View Controller :

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
AppDelegate *mainDelegate;
}

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSLog(@"Vars are :%@ , %@",mainDelegate.firstVariable,mainDelegate.secondVariable);
}
```